# How to set a postvar's name in a httprequest?

Tags: c#, post, web-services, httprequest

I need to reach a webservice which respondss to the postvar "data".
How do i set this name in c# with a httprequest...
this is what i got:

```
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData); 

            HttpWebRequest myRequest =
              (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://secreturl/jubidubb.php");
            myRequest.Method = "POST";
            myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            myRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();


            newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            // The response
            WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't *responds to the postvar "data"* simply mean that your `postData` string needs to be of the form `"data=mydata"`?

Comment: Without knowing more about the spec of the service you're using, it's impossible to say, but I'd guess your `postData` string needs to be of the form `data=my-json-encoded-data`...?

Comment: what i got in data now is : {"name":"rox", "age":"20"}

Comment: all i need to do is to give it a postname :P

Comment: Then try `data={"name":"rox", "age":"20"}`

Comment: Thank you. Will try it out tomorrow :)